# Swift Realm Limitation

Tags: swift, pagination, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

i need to make pagination in collection view so i want to limit the result coming from realm database this my load data code

```
var messageIndex: Results<MessageRealm>?

func loadMessage() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    if let userTitleName = user?.fromId {
    let mssagesRealm = realm.objects(UsersRealm.self).filter("sender = %@", userTitleName)
    for sub in mssagesRealm {
        messageIndex = sub.msgs.sorted(byKeyPath: "timeStamp")
        }
    }
}
```

i found this solution but is not working with me

```
let dogs = try! Realm().objects(Dog.self)
for i in 0..<5 {
    let dog = dogs[i]
}
```

any suggestion

Comment: So you only want to retrieve a certain number of elements from `messagesRealm`? What do you mean, the second example isn't working? Please be specific.

Comment: Yes i want to retrieve certain number from messageRealm and message realm is a list from userRealm...

Comment: for the second example its give me type of MessageRealm but i need Results<MessageRealm>? ...

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more variable(myIndex) in you class MessageRealm

```
@objc dynamic var myIndex : Int = 0
```

while inserting record in MessageRealm you should increase with +1 or index.advanced(by: 1).

while facing record you just need to pass range like 1 to 100 or 101 to 200

startIndex = 101
endIndex = 200

```
let arrData = realm.objects(MessageRealm.self).filter(){$0. myIndex >= startIndex && $0. myIndex <= endIndex }
```

thats it you just have to add logic for increase `myIndex` while inserting record in MessageRealm, and logic for `startIndex` and `endIndex` as par your requirement of project.